# Parsing pairs of integers from String[] Java

Tags: java, string, syntax, io, split

How would I go about parsing pairs of integers after the first string in a string array. In my while loop below, i've assigned the letter 'A','B','C', but now I'm trying to assign pairs of numbers to a class input eg. class X(int i, int j), does anyone have any tips of what to do from here?

```
An example input would be : 
A 32 12 34 12 
B 12 22 11 11
C 1  4   1  2

 public static void readFile(String f) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            String[] str;
            Scanner s;
            try {

                line = in.readLine();
                s = new Scanner(line);
                int number = s.nextInt();
                if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                    number = s.nextInt(); 
                } 
                s.close();
                line = in.readLine(); 
                numLines = Integer.parseInt(line);

                while((line = input.readLine())!=null){
                      String[] pair = line.split(" ");
                      String letter;        
                      letter = pair[0];
                  }

                if (!numLines.equals(lineCount)) { 
                System.exit(0);
                }           
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                in.close(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: You say you want to do something with the Integers, but all i see in your code is String.

Comment: This does not compile. You are closing `input` which is never defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the line and then parse individual numbers.

Something like this:

```
String[] a = {"A 32 12 34 12","B 12 22 11 11", "C 1  4   1  2"};
    
for (String s: a) {
    String[] line = s.split("\\s+");
    
    for (int i = 1; i < line.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(line[i]) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

> 32 12 34 12
>
> 12 22 11 11
>
> 1 4 1 2

For the sake of example, I am using array to show how it works. You can make changes based on your requirements. You note in question something about `class x(...)` but nothing in your code shows that so I won't bother to show something that I don't understand.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/GMm7kZ)